# How to draw a plain (non tranparent) line?

Tags: ios4, uiview, cgcontext

In a UIView inside the "-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect" method.
I want to draw a plain black line (as a border), but I always get a semi-transparent line.
Only the four points at the corners are perfectly black. 
Why is that?

Here is the mycode:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetAlpha(context,1.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context,0.0,0.0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,rect.size.width,0.0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,rect.size.width,rect.size.height);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,0.0,rect.size.height);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add border to a UIView, you can do it as below as well

```
yourView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
yourView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
```

Don't forget to import QuartzCore framework.